# Django - deployed, 403 for static but it should have permission, wsgi + Apache

Tags: python, django, apache

my deployed Django project can't access the static files, I get 403 for all of them when inspecting in Chrome.

I added the following to my 000-default.conf where I also have the WSGIScriptAlias etc.:

```
Alias /static/ /home/budget/static/deploy/
<Directory /home/budget/static/deploy>
Required all granted
</Directory/
```

The static files exist in the budget/static/deploy folder. Should this not give the required permissions? What do I have to change to get rid of the 403?

It is running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Edit:

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'budget/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    )

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/deploy/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a couple of different things that cause your configuration not to work. First of all, I would make sure that you are indeed modifying the proper Apache configuration file. You can run this command to check this:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[2]}' | sed s/\"//g
```

Then, to  delegate other API requests to django through WSGI, you should also give the correct permissions to your wsgi file (maybe this is not absolutely required for mere static serving to work):

```
<Directory /path/to/django/project/project>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

Next, set the process information to be used by Apache as well as your binding url for your project.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/path/to/django/project python-home=/path/to/your/venv
WSGIProcessGroup mydjangoproject
WSGIScriptAlias /binding/url /path/to/django/project/project/wsgi.py
```

Lastly, you may need to set up some permissions to allow www-data to read your media and static files and you should be all set. Don't forget to restart Apache to apply the modifications.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I have a snippet for wsgi.py like yours (but with the path to my project) so the configuration file should be correct. I added the `WSGIDaemonProcess` lines you provided, but that changed nothing. Lastly, I have given www-data ownership like so: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data deploy` (for each folder to be sure, I am unsure if that was necessary) and restarted Apache but nothing has changed.

Comment: what is the url that gives you a 403?  Have you checked that you edit the right configuration file?

Comment: You can give the permission as `sudo chmod -R 775 /home/budget/static/deploy`